# What's wrong with this PWM-controlled constant current sink?

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, constant-current, darlington

[image: PWM-Controlled current sink]

T10 gets very hot and starts melting within 30s, even with a heat sink and values way below its rated 15A.

Edit:
 I know it is not a true PWM controlled constant current, but that what I can do with the parts that I have access to. As for the current being used at, it does not exceed 4A at full duty of the 65kHz signal.

Edit 2: So, basically, what's wrong with my circuit is my inability to correctly use the information in the datasheet. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: At what current? Did you calculate the power dissipation in the transistor?

Comment: What type of heat sink are you using? What is the frequency and duty cycle is the PWM running at?

Comment: @XJ : look edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the load (2 ohm) is driven at 3 amps, it develops 6 volts across it and, conversely there is 6 volts from collector to ground because the supply is 12 volts. At this current the emitter resistor drops 1.5 volts therefore, the collector to emitter voltage has to equal 4.5 volts. So, the power dissipation in the transistor is 3 amps x 4.5 volts = 13.5 watts.

The thermal resistance of the transistor is 1.5 degC per watt and if this is on a Heatsink of (say) 10 degC per watt, the temperature rise of the transistor’s junction is 13.5 x 11.5 degC.

So, do you see the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

I would not call this a PWM controlled constant current sink. It is a linear current source that is being controlled by an analog voltage. The analog voltage is just being generated by a filtered PWM. It's heating up because it's linear current source, not a switching current source. The 15A rating of T1 isn't for operating as a linear device. It's for operating as a switch. That 15A rating is meaningless here. If you're expecting the efficiency of a switching circuit, don't because it isn't one. It is inefficient (and hot) in the same way a linear regulator is hot.

So it's operating as expected. You've basically built a linear regulator but have sized it according to the efficiency expected of a switching regulator. For something like this to produce 15A, you need parallel transistors with balancing measures, mounted to a heatsink and possibly a fan.

Comment: : look at edit. Most certainly I didn't expect it to work at switching regulator efficiency, but at least at a reasonable temperature like the lm338 linear regulator.

Answer (score 2):

With the shown 2 ohm resistor the dissipation in T10 is maximum at 2.4A (60% duty cycle on your PWM) when the transistor will be dissipating 14.4W, which is a lot for a TO-220 package. It will be more if R5 is lower.

It's also possible it's oscillating, which you can check with an oscilloscope, but I suspect the problem is simply power dissipation.

The [BDW93C](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bdw93c.pdf) is only capable of 80W, and for that you have to hold the **case** temperature to 25°C, which is rather difficult (and for that, the transistor die will be at 150°C, very very hot indeed).

BTW, if your PWM frequency is low, that little 10nF capacitor won't do a good job filtering. Cutoff is about 200Hz as shown.

---

The 12A (not 15A) maximum continuous collector collector current is only one limitation. The limitations stack up like a Venn diagram and  you have to obey all of them. Another limitation is the Safe Operating Area as shown in the datasheet figure. With 10V across the transistor the maximum DC current is 8A, at 12V 4A is the maximum permissible.

Answer (score 1):

Your output transistor isn't operating as on-off switch, it's total dissipation is = I(12V - I * 2,5Ohm) where I is the output current and R5+R6 is assumed to be 2,5Ohm. The max dissipation in the transistor occurs when I*2,5 Ohm = 6 volts; that means I=2,4A. Then the dissipation is 14,4 watts. I guess that's much more than you have assumed.

If you want to dissipate less consider to make a version where the output transistor is switched on-off and the current is smoothed with a series inductor like in constant current led drivers. The design details are beyond the scope of this answer.